# Is AppDomain.GetAssemblies() really supported in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In MSDN, it is said that [`AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` is supported in Silverlight 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies%28VS.95%29.aspx).

In my project, when I target the version 4 of Silverlight (I triple checked), I can't access to the `GetAssemblies()` method on `AppDomain` as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Cannot find GetAssemblies() method on AppDomain class in Silverlight 4]

If I try anyway, it won't compile. I can workaround this using the following piece of code:

```
dynamic domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var assemblies = domain.GetAssemblies();
```

It compiles and seem to be working fine but only under Silverlight client 5.X and Silverlight 4.0.60351 and above from my tests. It doesn't work for below versions of the client.
The project in question is the entry point of my Silverlight application.

Googling on this topic mainly says that it is supported...

So my questions are:

- **a)** Is it really supported and if so how can I use it to ensure it will always work as long as my clients are using *any* of the 4.X version?
- **b)** How can I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` in the IDE without the above workaround? Is there something I missed?

In case it can be useful, I have the following installed on my desktop:

- Silverlight client 5.1.10411
- Silverlight SDK 3, 4 and 5
- Silverlight 4 Toolkit April 2010
- Silverlight 4 Tools for VS2010

I didn't try to uninstall/reinstall anything (yet) to avoid losing a whole day in this tedious task...

--

Edit: It appears that `GetAssemblies()` method is not present on `AppDomain` class in mscorlib.dll for SL4. So I guess MSDN documentation is incorrect and the runtime SL4 client has been patched at some point for some reason (compatibility with SL5-compiled applications?)...

Comment: I cant see GetData method in your linked msdn page. Try to press F1 on CurrentDomain and see where you will be linked.

Comment: @Reniuz it brings me to the help regarding .NET Framework 4, not Silverlight :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also stumpled upon these (see my comment [on MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies%28VS.95%29.aspx#1)) behavior or wrong documentation in the MSDN and tried many diffrent ways to get the method call GetAssemblies in Siverlight 4. The solution for me was to install Silverlight 5 and change my silverlight project to work with Silverlight 5.

My suggestion is that the method GetAssemblies was added later, by a patch or silverlight update to the silverlight runtime.

Comment: It probably makes sense that it was added in a patch. Not sure if it's very clean from Microsoft guys. In any case, the documentation is definitely not matching the actual Framework in this case. I wish I could fine more information about this but I found virtually nothing. I gave a try to compile under SL5, it's working but not sure we can move the whole application to SL5...

Comment: @Guillaume. It depends on what other components (aka. Prism) you are using. But normally all components are now available for SL5. And for me there was no problem to switch from SL4 to SL5.

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone could answer exactly on the why and the how but doesn't seem so. Your answer seems quite accurate and matches my guesses so I mark it as accepted. However, I won't be able to compile against SL5 indeed because of some third party libraries we are using. Instead I use the workaround given here: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/590383.aspx It's enough for my needs as I really need to parse only the assemblies in our solution and not really all of them. Thanks!